# Dynamic selection of product variants, comparing 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Sorry for the bad title, couldn't figure a better one.

**Product Options:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5cdd1e81e85ecc7ebb145039",
    "name": "Sizes S/M - M/L - L/XL ",
    "display_name": "Size",
    "display_style": "rectangle",
    "values": [
      {
        "_id": "5cdd1e81e85ecc7ebb14503a",
        "label": "Small / Medium",
        "option_id": "5cdd1e81e85ecc7ebb145039"
      },
      {
        "_id": "5cdd1e81e85ecc7ebb14503b",
        "label": "Large / X-Large",
        "option_id": "5cdd1e81e85ecc7ebb145039"
      },
      {
        "_id": "5da8080ea51d8207e9098875",
        "label": "Medium / Large",
        "option_id": "5cdd1e81e85ecc7ebb145039"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
     "_id": "5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145040",
    "name": "Hat Sizes Νο 56-57 / 58-59 / 60-61",
    "display_name": "Hat Size",
    "display_style": "rectangle",
    "values": [
      {
        "_id": "5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145041",
        "label": "56 / 57",
        "option_id": "5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145040"
      },
      {
        "_id": "5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145042",
        "label": "58 / 59",
        "option_id": "5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145040"
      },
      {
        "_id": "5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145043",
        "label": "60 / 61 ",
        "option_id": "5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145040"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Product Variants:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5e0a02e4413f9e12f20edfb5",
    "options": [
      {
        "option": {
          "_id": "5cdd1e81e85ecc7ebb145039",
          "display_name": "Size",
          "display_style": "rectangle"
        },
        "value": {
          "_id": "5cdd1e81e85ecc7ebb14503a",
          "label": "Small / Medium",
          "option_id": "5cdd1e81e85ecc7ebb145039"
        }
      },
      {
        "option": {
          "_id": "5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145040",
          "display_name": "Size Hat",
          "display_style": "rectangle"
        },
        "value": {
          "_id": "5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145041",
          "label": "56 / 57",
          "option_id": "5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145040"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5e0a02e4413f9e12f20edfb6",
    "options": [
      {
        "option": {
          "_id": "5cdd1e81e85ecc7ebb145039",
          "display_name": "Size",

          "display_style": "rectangle"
        },
        "value": {
          "_id": "5cdd1e81e85ecc7ebb14503a",
          "label": "Small / Medium",
          "option_id": "5cdd1e81e85ecc7ebb145039"
        }
      },
      {
        "option": {
          "_id": "5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145040",
          "display_name": "Size Hat",
          "display_style": "rectangle"
        },
        "value": {
          "_id": "5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145042",
          "label": "58 / 59",
          "option_id": "5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145040"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5e0a02e4413f9e12f20edfb9",
    "options": [
      {
        "option": {
          "_id": "5cdd1e81e85ecc7ebb145039",
          "display_name": "Size",
          "display_style": "rectangle"
        },
        "value": {
          "_id": "5cdd1e81e85ecc7ebb14503b",
          "label": "Large / X-Large",
          "option_id": "5cdd1e81e85ecc7ebb145039"
        }
      },
      {
        "option": {
          "_id": "5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145040",
          "display_name": "Size Hat",
          "display_style": "rectangle"
        },
        "value": {
          "_id": "5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145042",
          "label": "58 / 59",
          "option_id": "5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145040"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5e0a02e4413f9e12f20edfba",
    "options": [
      {
        "option": {
          "_id": "5cdd1e81e85ecc7ebb145039",
          "display_name": "Size",
          "display_style": "rectangle"
        },
        "value": {
          "_id": "5cdd1e81e85ecc7ebb14503b",
          "label": "Large / X-Large",
          "option_id": "5cdd1e81e85ecc7ebb145039"
        }
      },
      {
        "option": {
          "_id": "5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145040",
          "display_name": "Size Hat",
          "display_style": "rectangle"
        },
        "value": {
          "_id": "5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145043",
          "label": "60 / 61 ",
          "option_id": "5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145040"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5e0a02e4413f9e12f20edfbc",
    "options": [
      {
        "option": {
          "_id": "5cdd1e81e85ecc7ebb145039",
          "display_name": "Size",
          "display_style": "rectangle"
        },
        "value": {
          "_id": "5da8080ea51d8207e9098875",
          "label": "Medium / Large",
          "option_id": "5cdd1e81e85ecc7ebb145039"
        }
      },
      {
        "option": {
          "_id": "5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145040",
          "display_name": "Size Hat",
          "display_style": "rectangle"
        },
        "value": {
          "_id": "5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145042",
          "label": "58 / 59",
          "option_id": "5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145040"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5e0a02e4413f9e12f20edfbb",
    "options": [
      {
        "option": {
          "_id": "5cdd1e81e85ecc7ebb145039",
          "display_name": "Size",
          "display_style": "rectangle"
        },
        "value": {
          "_id": "5da8080ea51d8207e9098875",
          "label": "Medium / Large",
          "option_id": "5cdd1e81e85ecc7ebb145039"
        }
      },
      {
        "option": {
          "_id": "5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145040",
          "display_name": "Size Hat",
          "display_style": "rectangle"
        },
        "value": {
          "_id": "5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145041",
          "label": "56 / 57",
          "option_id": "5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145040"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have this code (part of React component):

```
setVariant = (optionIndex, valueIndex) => {
    const { product } = this.state;
    const parentProduct = { ...product };

    const optionValue = parentProduct.options[optionIndex].values[valueIndex];

    const emptyArr = [];

    parentProduct.variants.forEach(({ options }) => {
      options.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.value._id === optionValue._id) {
          emptyArr.push(...options);
        }
      });
    });

    const updatedOptions = parentProduct.options.map((productOption) => {
      const productOptions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(productOption));

      productOptions.values = productOptions.values.map((productOptionValue) => {
        productOptionValue.disabled = emptyArr.every(
          ({ value: { _id } }) => productOptionValue._id !== _id
        );
        return productOptionValue;
      });
      return productOptions;
    });
```

My issue with this snippet it that it sets the disabled property correctly ex. if I choose first `Size` e.x. `Small/Medium`, then `Size Hat` `60 / 61` gets disabled and I can click the other two options. But if I click another `Size Hat` `58 / 59` then `Large / X-Large` won't get enabled.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: desired result]

But this is what i'm getting: (when changing `56 / 57` etc. then `Sizes` ex. `Large/X-Large` should be enabled if found in variants array, red color represents disabled button)

[image]

Comment: I realized that I am not going to be able to explain it properly; so I wrote a code to show that it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-pascal-tqh44. The code in the sandbox is just a refactored version of your `setVariant` function. So, I did not really change the logic of your code except for trying to accommodate for the parts that were not available to me. `setVariant` function did not have any problems in it. My guess is that your update logic is doing something fishy:

Comment: Thanks @Gasim for the comment/solution and the effort for creating a sandbox, I think there is a small bug. Click `Small/Medium` -> `58/59`, then `Hat Size` should have `56/57` enabled too since this combination exists. Same applies if you click `Large/X-Large`,  initially `58/59`, `60/61` is enabled (as it should), but if I click `58/59` then `60/61` is disabled even though the combination exists. We're close but can't figure out how to solve this... Try to play with combinations, you'll hit a dead end! Happy New Year!

Comment: [Cant edit previous comment],  you must click again `Large/X-Large` in order to re-enable `60/61`

Comment: This is because in your original code, you are selecting options based on a single item. If click "S / M", you get going to get "56 / 57" and "58 / 59" because you found two variants: `"S / M" + "56 / 57" and "S / M" + "58 / 59"`. When you click "56 / 57", you get two variants `"S / M" + "56 / 57" and "M / L" + "56 / 57"`. As result, you lose "56 / 57" and "57 / 58." I think the simplest fix would be checking all available variants.

Comment: I tried to fix it a little bit (same url): https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-pascal-tqh4. By using the selected options to find available variations. However, it still has a bug. You need to make sure that if you click select an option from one (e.g Size, 56 / 57), all the relative groups must be available (59 / 59). Because you are only using variations array to find the available options, you will need another way to enable neighbor options. It shouldn't be hard to figure it out.

Comment: @StathisNtonas, can't see bugs in the aforementioned sandbox. Can you point them out?

Comment: @x00 points the bug in the comment above yours, thanks for the comment!

Comment: @StathisNtonas, read it. Don't get it. Pushed the buttons - saw nothing. Can you elaborate?

Comment: no, seriously, you should first `normalize` the data somehow (a simple matrix like suggested from @maksimr), and then just `filter` your options based on the requirements (selected options), it would be much simpler, than handling what you get from the server directly. IMO

Answer (score 6):

You can create a map for every option's value which would have a reference on the corresponding values of other options. For example, a map for Size values should look like:

```
{
  sizeValueIdA: [hatSizeValueA, hatSizeValueB],
  sizeValueIdB: [hatSizeValueB],
  sizeValueIdC: []
}
```

So with this map, you can easily get a list of available Hat Size values knowing selected Size's value.

This is an example of code that allows you to get a list of Hat Size values by Size value id and vice versa. I think that with this data you can easily disable options in UI if they not in these lists

```
const sizeToHatSize = convertOptionToValueMap(productOptions[0]);
const hatSizeToSize = convertOptionToValueMap(productOptions[1]);

productVariants.forEach(variant => {
  const sizeValueId = variant.options[0].value._id;
  let hatSizeValueId = variant.options[1].value._id;
  sizeToHatSize[sizeValueId].push(hatSizeValueId);
  hatSizeToSize[hatSizeValueId].push(sizeValueId);
});

function convertOptionToValueMap(option) {
  return option.values.reduce((dict, sizeOptionValue) => {
    dict[sizeOptionValue._id] = [];
    return dict;
  }, {});
}

describe('59543685', function() {
  it('should return available Hat Sizes for selected Size', function() {
    const sizeValueId = '5cdd1e81e85ecc7ebb14503a';
    expect(sizeToHatSize[sizeValueId]).toEqual([
      '5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145041',
      '5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145042',
    ]);
  });

  it('should return available Sizes for selected Hat Size', function() {
    const hatSizeValueId = '5cdd280ce85ecc7ebb145041';
    expect(hatSizeToSize[hatSizeValueId]).toEqual([
      '5cdd1e81e85ecc7ebb14503a',
      '5da8080ea51d8207e9098875'
    ]);
  });
});
```

In my example, I have used arrays but you can choose a map instead of array for fast checking that an option is available.

```
const siteToHatSize = {
  sizeValueIdA: {hatSizeValueA: true, hatSizeValueB: true},
  sizeValueIdB: {hatSizeValueB: true},
  sizeValueIdC: {}
}

const isEnabled = siteToHatSize[selectedSizeValueId][hatSizeId] // you can use it in render function
```

Also, in your case, with only 2 options you can also look one the problem as a 2-dimensional matrix. Every variant is just an intersection between row(Hat Size's value) and Column(Size's value).

```
[          /*Small*/ /*Medium*/ /*Large*/ 
 /*56-57*/ [     1,          0,        1],
 /*58-59*/ [     1,          1,        0],
 /*60-61*/ [     0,          0,        1],
]
```

Maybe this would be more appropriate structure for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been more than 3 years since the question was asked, but I faced the same problem while building an e-commerce application.

The approach I took was to first make an array of all available variants:

```
const possibleCombinations = variants.map((variant) =>
  variant.options.flatMap((opt) => opt.value._id)
);
```

The state for the selected combination was kept as key-value pairs in a react use state.

`{ [attribute._id]: value._id }`

Then it's just a matter of filtering the combinations by the selected value ids. In my case, I created an `isDisabled` function that was used to enable/disable styles on the radio input.

```
const isDisabled = (valueId: string): boolean => {
    const currentCombination = Object.values(selected);

    if (currentCombination.length === 0) return false;

    const filteredVariants = possibleCombinations.filter((variant) => {
      return currentCombination.every((id) => variant.includes(id));
    });

    const restOfOptions = uniq(filteredVariants.flat());

    return !restOfOptions.includes(valueId);
  };
```

Here is a link to the whole POC for the product variant selector built with React+Typescript using the data provided in the question - https://wskihn-5173.preview.csb.app/

Hope it helps someone who has struggled.